# Converting categorical columns to numerical values

Tags: r

I want to convert categorical columns in the dataset to be numerical values (1,2,3, etc).
How can I do this in R?

```
## Load vcd package
library(vcd)

## Load Arthritis dataset (data frame)
data(Arthritis)

Arthritis <- Arthritis[,2:5]

head(Arthritis)

  Treatment  Sex Age Improved
1   Treated Male  27     Some
2   Treated Male  29     None
3   Treated Male  30     None
4   Treated Male  32   Marked
5   Treated Male  46   Marked
6   Treated Male  58   Marked
```

Resulting dataset would look like this:

```
      Treatment Sex Age Improved
 [1,]         1   1  27        1
 [2,]         1   1  29        0
 [3,]         1   1  30        0
 [4,]         1   1  32        2
 [5,]         1   1  46        2
 [6,]         1   1  58        2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of variables is huge, you may consider using this automation:

```
Arthritis2 <- sapply(Arthritis, unclass)
```

Edit:

```
Arthritis2 <- sapply(Arthritis, unclass) - 1
```

Comment: This is good but I want the classes to begin at 0, is this possible with unclass?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using named list and `match` function:

```
scores <- list("0" = "None", "1" = "Some", "2" = "Marked" )
Arthritis$Scores <- names(scores)[match(Arthritis$Improved, scores)]
head(Arthritis)
    
   Sex Age Improved Scores
1 Male  27     Some      1
2 Male  29     None      0
3 Male  30     None      0
4 Male  32   Marked      2
5 Male  46   Marked      2
6 Male  58   Marked      2
```

If you don't want to keep `Improved` column, simply do this instead:

```
Arthritis$Improved <- names(scores)[match(Arthritis$Improved, scores)]
```